# Fermat's little theorem and modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

> Fermat's little theorem:
>   $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge p \in \mathbb{P}$ then $a^{p}\equiv a\pmod p .$
>
> Proof: 
>   $a \equiv r\pmod p . $
>
> $\exists 0\leq r\leq p$
>   and $a^{p}\equiv r^{p} \pmod p .$

Case $r\neq 0$:

Note that $\exists r \in (0,p] $
$r \in \bar{U}\left ( p \right )$ and$ \left | \bar{U} \right |=p-1$

By a corollary of Lagrange's theorem: $\forall a \in G \;(a^{ | G  |}=e).$

Thus, $ r^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p .$

By Lagrange's theorem, $r^{p-1}=e$ but how is this equal to $1 \pmod p?$ I haven't any classes in number theory so I'm picking up as I go along.

Comment: What's the identity element in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$?

Comment: I assume you're using an alternative notation to the set of positive integers less than p and coprime to p. The identity element in $\bar{U}$=1 since the operation in this set is multiplicative. The modulo operation is multiplicative.@carmichael561

Comment: You can type  A\equiv B \pmod C, which yields $A\equiv B\pmod C$. My edit was just for formatting and punctuation, and a few brackets for style.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily conclude Fermat's lil Theorem from Euler's Theorem:

$Euler's \; Theorem$ : let $m\in \mathbb N$ be a Natural number and $a \in \mathbb Z$ is an integer which are co-prime e.g. $(a,m)=1$ then $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv1 (mod \; m)$

where $\phi(m)$ is Euler's function and enumerates number of Natural numbers  like n which are less than m and are co-prime with m e.g. $(n,m)=1$ .replacing $m$ with $p$ and you will get your answer cause $\phi(p)=p-1$. also the proof of Euler's Theorem is in Below Link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem